# Partial function as a type of binary relation

Tags: functions

Can a partial function be defined as *a binary relation that is right-unique**?

* $\forall x \in X$ and $y, z \in Y: xRy \land xRz \Rightarrow y = z$

Comment: Please include the definitions you are working with so people can make sense of the question.

Comment: @rschwieb done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Also known as functional.